# Making Plone site temporarily static for high traffic peak

Tags: apache, plone, cdn, varnish

We know there is a surge of traffic hitting a Plone site on a certain day. Last time this happened we couldn't crank enough power out of Plone to make it run smoothly.

Now I am asking what kind of tricks one could play to feed the horde temporarily? E.g.

- Convert (part of) Plone site to static HTML files and images on a disk, serving them through Apache?
- Cache the whole site in Varnish with very long expire time
- Using some CDN service which automatically mirrors the site

We can change the site DNS if needed, but I hope all this could be achieved having contact form and other HTTP POST forms still working (if necessary we can hide them temporary)

Comment: One plone site we do sees traffic spikes more than any other plone site out in the wild I think. You just need to make sure things are getting cached correctly and that EVERY resources at least has some kind of upstream caching. We use a CDN along with varnish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go with Varnish and something like a 60 second TTL. This is enough, because it means you'll get only a handful of requests per minute.

You need to test carefully, though, that response headers are set correctly so you don't have any "holes" in the cache that hammer Zope. Funkload to the rescue.

Martin

Comment: Thanks. Varnish handled it well :)